# Category Image Information not displayed once image uploaded after version upgrade to 2.3.3

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.3, category-image

I have one strange issue previously i was using magento 2.2.2 version in which category image upload works perfectly, after upgraded to magento 2.3.3 version image was uploaded first time but after that if i only save the category that image was not found the image name will "_1", "_1_1" and saved into database.

For this issue i have followed this patch https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25209, after that image saved properly but the information below image preview have some issue as seen in below screenshot:
[image]
https://prnt.sc/s8kwip

Does anyone face this type of issue after version upgrade to 2.3.3?

> Note: In Fresh version of magento 2.3.3 doesn't have issue it occurs
>   only after version upgrade to 2.3.3 from command line as per magento
>   devdocs guideline.

Thanks in Advance. !

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the **attribute image** of the category matches with the **attribute set**

Comment: Nothing was changed, before magento version upgrade it was working properly, issue comes after version upgrade.